# Wait for two buttons to be clicked in QML interface

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, qml, qtquick2

I am despairing once again. I've added a QML interface to an existing QT C++ Application. Know I want to implement something like this:

The user wants to connect to pictures to let them skip synchronously. So he clicks on a button called "connect", then on the first picture and after that on the second picture. The signals of the buttons come with a id, so the connect-Function knows which pictures were clicked and sends a final signal to the c++ part.

I want something like this:

```
signal connectGalleys(int id1, int id2)
function connectIDs(){
    var id1
    var id2
    id1 = waitFor(onButtonClicked(id))
    id2 = waitFor(onButtonClicked(id))
    saveConnection(id1,id2)
 }
 onConnectClicked: connectIDs()
```

So, does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't have a method 'wait' like this, since you must finish your call to `connectIDs` for the event loop to take over, and be able to do anything with your GUI (including selecting pictures).

The solution is to have "software modes", and when you clic on `connect`, you change the mode to, for instance `connectMode`, and returns. Now, when you click on one picture, you may check if the mode is `connectMode`, and mark it as selected. If another picture was already selected, then you call in addition `connectFinished()`, that does whatever you need to do to connect them, then turn back the software in `normalMode`.